# Program closes when non-verified user tries to sign in

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, email-validation

I have set up email verification for user authentication, but I am running into an issue. If a user tries to log in before they verify their account, the app closes but gives no error.

This is the block of code that signs the user in and checks to see if they are verified or not.

```
    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    //if the task is successfull
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        //start the profile activity
                        finish();
                        if(firebaseUser != null && firebaseUser.isEmailVerified()) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomePage.class));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please verify your email by following the link that has been sent to your" +
                                    " email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressDialog.hide();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login was not successful, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressDialog.hide();
                    }
                    }
                });
```

The logcat does print some errors, but I can't tell if any of them actually pertain to this issue or not. This is what it prints out.

```
    2019-02-24 00:01:27.870 2246-2693/? E/albn: Phenotype API error. Event # bsvs@c80ac253, EventCode: GET_COMMITTED_CONFIGURATION [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
    alaj: 29503
        at albu.a(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):40)
        at albt.b(Unknown Source:2)
        at albn.a(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):103)
        at albn.a(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):97)
        at yvi.run(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):27)
        at bgjq.run(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):2)
        at rnb.run(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at rsw.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-02-24 00:01:27.872 2246-2693/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=51, operation=GetCommittedConfigurationOperationCall
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 29503, resolution=null}]
        at albn.a(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):111)
        at albn.a(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):97)
        at yvi.run(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):27)
        at bgjq.run(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):2)
        at rnb.run(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at rsw.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-02-24 00:01:27.877 2246-2783/? E/NetRec: [91] ailh.a: Could not retrieve server token for package com.google.android.apps.gcs
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: qgu: 29503: 
        at asbm.b(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):2)
        at asbm.a(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):29)
        at ailh.a(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):1)
        at ailh.a(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):4)
        at aile.getHeaders(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):2)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):9)
        at rgd.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):1)
        at brn.executeRequest(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):1)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):10)
        at rge.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):13)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.a(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):7)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):2)
     Caused by: qgu: 29503: 
        at qmn.a(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):3)
        at akzo.b(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):3)
        at albt.a(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):7)
        at yvc.a(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):5)
        at yvi.run(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):34)
        at bgjq.run(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):2)
        at rnb.run(:com.google.android.gms@15090040@15.0.90 (100700-231259764):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at rsw.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Place `finish()` in the `else` part of `if(firebaseUser != null....)`.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal I placed the finish after the `Toast` that tells the user to verify their account via the link, but the app still closes

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Placing it in the first `if statement` before the `else` in `if(firebaseUser != null....)` worked for me